# Converting a Single Model Endpoint to Multi Model Endpoint

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I have the following situation - My deployed model in Sagemaker is not doing well, so I have re-trained the model. Will it be possible for me to convert my existing single model endpoint to multi model model endpoint, so that I can access both my older model version as well as the newer version?

Or in case I deploy a Multi model endpoint can I add a new model to my multi model endpoint after the endpoint's deployment?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, first invoke [CreateEndpointConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateEndpointConfig.html) specifying a `ProductionVariant` for both your old and new model. Next, invoke [UpdateEndpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateEndpoint.html) to update your existing endpoint with the new config. Your existing single endpoint will be automatically converted into a multi-model endpoint.

You can follow this same process to add new model(s) to your multi-model endpoint.